# Компоновка dll в exe по Рихтеру

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо сделать следующее:    Exe + .DLL => один EXE

Решение данной проблемы взял [отсюда](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/microsoft_press/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition), но код не работает

[image: Imgur]

Программа и проект, из которого был создан dll
[Папка](https://mega.co.nz/#F!I1di3LiZ!xkVajVqr4gTdyy8RBQncbA) или [Архив](https://mega.co.nz/#!ht1TUQCT!wY8_ebcjU4dzyFHba6pdP5nNAWfQWx8chvJmnFwT_7M), кому как больше нравится.

slt.Abc() возвращает 0.
Анонимная функция не вызывается (если закомментировать содержимое Test() )

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: А Вы свою библиотеку в `References` добавили?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, .dll-библиотека у вас нативная, на неуправляемом коде; или, как и приложение, написана под .NET?

Comment: @Donil, получилось, добавил ту же сборку в    References    установил     Копировать локально     в     false     и заработало

Comment: @Shad, сборка была на NET