# Компоновка dll в exe по Рихтеру

Tags: c#, .net

Великие знатоки, прошу вашей помощи в нелегкой задаче.

[**Продолжение этой темы**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/327958/c-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-dll-%D0%B2-exe-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83)

[Программа](https://mega.co.nz/#!o00S3QgA!6xlxqwBrr8Ae1yvcl2KlEGV0jtcMtjjJ8vYxwWSG_vQ) на WPF, которая использует NAudio.dll, которую я и хочу включить в .exe

Вот как выглядит  [рабочий процесс](http://i62.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0613/66/70cb0c17b0d49f13e25e31fdf0697466.png), [ошибка](http://i62.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0613/4f/e1650289b624f84d51bbadc5986ce84f.png)

Программа создает окно-гитару, на которой можно играть.

Comment: Посмотрите в `ViewDetail... -> InnerException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем проблема в том, что версия Вашей библиотеки `naudio` была не той. Пользуйтесь инструментом `nuget`, тем более что в 2012 студии он уже сразу установлен.